# How to know when you scrolled down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just visit http://techcrunch.com/ and scroll down. How do they do it? How that top line appears with a new logo? Is there any jQuery trick? How to determine when person scrolled down certain amount of pixels and show to him new html?

Comment: @guido is right. If you look at the page with Chrome's developer tools you can see the sonar function:
    <script src="http://o.aolcdn.com/os_merge/?file=/aol/jquery.sonar.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            $("img[data-src]").bind("scrollin", {distance:500}, function(){
         
                var img = this,
                    $img = $(img);
                
                $img.unbind("scrollin"); // clean up binding
                img.src = $img.attr( "data-src" );
                
            });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They might just use [jQuery-Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/) which lets you trigger events if the user "*passes*" a certain HTML-Element.

Example ( taken from page ):

```
    $('.entry').waypoint(function() {
       alert('You have scrolled to an entry.');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

They are using jquery sonar plugin[1] which defines special jquery events[2].

The trick is putting a static positioned top element, on a very high z-index layer, with the part to be occupied by the dynamic logo initially transparent. When the jquery event is thrown, they just make the new logo visible above any underlying content.

[1] http://artzstudio.com/files/jquery-boston-2010/jquery.sonar/jquery.sonar.js
[2] http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/jquery-special-events/#api

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they use `window.pageYOffset` and there is also `document.documentElement.scrollHeight` and finally they use the `window.onscroll` event.

Answer (score 0):

They use the window.scroll() function to listen for the scroll event, then use window.scrollTop() to determine the offset of the logo from the top of the page.
see: http://jsfiddle.net/XkMrc/2/